# remove margin/padding/spacing around QTableView within QTabWidget

Tags: qt, qt-designer

any way to remove  margin/padding/spacing around QTableView within QTabWidget(ui files [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1xn0Xe_-Mfj4OkPn1VHXDe38LOnydIwt4))? Qt Style Sheets or code is welcome .

[image]

Comment: Not enough information as you haven't shown the object hierarchy. If you simply dropped the QTableView inside the tab and set a layout, so that you have the hierarchy tabWidget (QTabWidget) > tab (QWidget) > tableView (QTableView), then open the tab (QWidget) in the Property Editor and remove the margins in the Layout section.

Comment: [without code its just a guess](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlayout.html#setContentsMargins)

Comment: @replete " in the Property Editor and remove the margins in the Layout section", worked, thanks!!!

Comment: @Jonas QLayout::setContentsMargins(int left, int top, int right, int bottom) also worked, thanks!!!